# Does this series converge or diverge ? and how to prove it

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following Sequence $a_n$ that is defind on the following way:

for each $n \geq 0$
$$\begin{array}{l}a_1=5\\a_{n+1}=\sqrt[n]na_n\end{array}$$
now the question is if the following series converge or diverge.
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $$
I tried to look on the elements and they seem to be increasing which makes me think it is converging but how I can prove it ?

Comment: Yes, they are increasing, but they could be increasing without bound.

Comment: I guess you mean $a_n$ converges, not the sum of them. And the answer to that is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  note that $\sqrt[n]n \gt 1$, so $a_{n+1} \gt a_n$

Comment: I tried to prove it by induction which lead me to the following inequality $\sqrt[{n+1}]{n+1}\;>\;\sqrt[n]n$ i tried few numbers on the calculator which seems to be true, I have no idea how to prove it and i am kind of confused because i know that the limit as n goes to infinity of $\;\sqrt[n]n$ is equal to 1

Comment: But this shows that all the $a$s are greater than $5$, so the sum of $k$ of them is greater than $5k$ and it diverges.  We don't care about how $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ compares to $\sqrt[n]n$, just that they are both at least $1$.  The question does not ask whether the $a_n$s converge, it asks about the sum of them.